# Convertir modelos de Tensorflow 1 a Tensorflow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, redes-neuronales

Dispongo de varios modelos creados en Tensorflow 1 que quisiera convertir a modelos de Tensorflow 2. Los modelos que tengo constan de tres ficheros del tipo de:

```
modelo1.model.data-00000-of-00001
modelo1.model.index
modelo1.model.meta
```

y desearía transformarlos en modelos en formato SavedModel de TF2. ¿Existe alguna forma de hacerlo directamente, sin tener que reescribir el código y entrenar de nuevo la red neuronal?

Como alternativa, en el script "compatibilizado" para TF2 hay las siguientes líneas de código para salvar y restaurar el modelo:

```
self.session = tf.compat.v1.Session()
init = tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()
self.session.run(init)
self.saver = tf.compat.v1.train.Saver()
...

def save_model(self, model_path):
    self.saver.save(self.session, model_path)

def restore_model(self, model_path):
    self.saver.restore(self.session, model_path)
```

¿Se podría reemplazar esas líneas por otras que salven el modelo en formato SavedModel de TF2? En caso afirmativo, ¿cómo?